# c++ размещение объекта в заранее выделенной памяти

Tags: c++

Как разместить объект в выделенной памяти? К примеру у меня есть выделенный массив размером 100:

```
std::allocator<char> alloc;
char* buffer = alloc.allocate(100);
```

как разместить объект в заданном месте выделенного массива? Я знаю что оператор new позволяет разместить объект в памяти:

```
Pl*  p = new(buffer)Pl(1,2,"");
```

но возможно ли указать оператору new куда именно  он должен разместить этот объект? На какой именно позиции массива buffer он должен разместить этот объект?

Comment: Если нужно со сдвигом - укажите его, типа, `buffer+offset`...

Comment: Harry, спасибо.

Comment: Harry, а если я допустим обнулил ссылку на этот объект, так как объект находится в буфере, я могу снова извлечь из буфера, как это сделать?

Comment: Недопонял... Обнулили `p`? Ну, наверное, можно пробовать `p = (Pl*)(buffer+offset)`, но... "*меня терзают смутные сомнения*" Да и смысл не хранить указатель на объект? так и до утечки недалеко :)

Comment: @cvxbcvbsdfsddfgdfg Это уже годится на новый вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Поясню чуть более развёрнуто.

Что делает обычный ператор `new` в C++? Он выполняет два главных действия: 1) выделяет память под объект; 2) вызывает конструктор объекта. Однако, помимо обычного оператора `new`, C++ предоставляет ещё один его вид - `new` ***с параметрами***. В коде он вызывается так:

```
TYPE* pObject = new(параметры) TYPE;
```

А определяется так:

```
void* operator new(std::size_t, список_параметров) {...}
```

В сущности, он делает то же самое, что и обычный `new`, но ему передаются некоторые дополнительные параметры, которые позволяют определённым образом модифицировать его поведение. Какие именно параметры передавать, сколько их должно быть, и как именно оператор `new` будет ими распоряжаться, стандартом C++ не определено - тут почти полная свобода у программиста. Однако в заголовочном файле new стандартной библиотеки можно найти следующие строки (GCC):

```
// Default placement versions of operator new.
_GLIBCXX_NODISCARD inline void* operator new(std::size_t, void* __p) _GLIBCXX_USE_NOEXCEPT
{ return __p; }
_GLIBCXX_NODISCARD inline void* operator new[](std::size_t, void* __p) _GLIBCXX_USE_NOEXCEPT
{ return __p; }
```

Это и есть определения т.н. ***размещающих*** операторов `new` (placement new). В принципе, их можно определить собственноручно, без использования заголовочного файла new и внутрикомпиляторных директив-примочек. Выглядеть это будет вот так (более наглядно):

```
inline void* operator new(std::size_t, void* p)   {return p;}
inline void* operator new[](std::size_t, void* p) {return p;}
```

Что же делают эти *placement new*? Из кода выше видно, что вместо того, чтобы динамически выделить память под объект(ы) и возвратить на неё указатель, эти версии в качестве дополнительного параметра принимают *указатель на уже подготовленную память* и тупо его возвращают. И как уже было сказано в самом начале, вызывают конструктор(ы) объект(а/ов) (код вызова конструктора вставляется компилятором *автоматически*, после вызова *функции* `operator new(...)`).

Прочитав и осознав выше написанное, вам сразу должно стать ясно, что для того, чтобы ***разместить объект в заданном месте выделенного массива***, надо просто передать *размещающему* оператору `new` ***указатель на заданное место выделенного массива***:

```
Pl*  p = new(buffer+index) Pl(1,2,"");
```

Разумеется, вы должны на сто процентов быть уверены, что: а) `buffer` содержит указатель на корректно выделенный массив; б) значение `index` не выходит за границы массива: в) размер оставшейся части массива по указателю `buffer+index` больше, либо равен `sizeof(Pl)`.

И да, в финале работы объект должен быть корректно удалён. Что в данном случае означает вызов его деструктора. Placement-версии оператора `delete` в C++ нет, однако разрешён прямой вызов деструктора (в отличие от конструктора). Что, собственно, и требуется осуществить:

```
p->~Pl();
```

Answer (score 0):

Pl*  p = new(&buffer[pos])Pl(1,2,"");

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]